# Are questions about running Ubuntu Mobile on X smartphone on topic?

Tags: discussion

With the announcement of this Android based Ubuntu derivative some questions other than what it was have started to pop out, such as "I have X brand of smartphone, will it run Ubuntu Mobile?".

I consider this questions *off topic* on the grounds that are about an unreleased, just announced, no development build available, version of Ubuntu that was showed running on a specific smartphone thereby not sure if it will run on other hardware just by "Installing it" or in an official manner. And in any case, how is any user going to answer when as I said, there's no way of knowing if it will run on other hardware?.

Are these questions on topic?.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While these aren't necessarily *off-topic* they're just poor question. Instead we should create a canonical question "What hardware will work with Ubuntu Mobile" and a solid canonical answer either pointing to a resources to find this out our a maintained list of all the models known to be supported.

At this time there are no known models of support since it has not been released yet. Though I think that's an acceptable answer for the canonical question :)

- Maybe like [this?](https://askubuntu.com/q/236276/41)

Comment: Yes, that should be enough to point new users asking for this to a realistic answer.

Comment: Sure, but then how should we tag them? *runs away*

Answer (score 0):

Until the software for the UI for "Ubuntu for phones" is released, yes, it is off-topic.

We don't accept questions about Ubuntu+1, why should we accept questions about a UI that hasn't been released yet?

On the other hand, attempting to run Ubuntu on a tablet or a smartphone is definitely on-topic, and should be tagged with [mobile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mobile).

Comment: "On the other hand, attempting to run Ubuntu on a tablet or a smartphone is definitely on-topic" - Wouldn't that be too localized?. Say, I have a Galaxy S 2 and I want to run Ubuntu on it, is Ask Ubuntu the proper support channel? or are the Ubuntu Forums a better option?.

Comment: @Uri Herrera: No, it's not too localized. It's perfectly conceivable that someone else would want to do the same, and would find the question useful.